# Why is my fluid sim is phasing through the obstacle?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I was trying to do an experiment so that my fluid would stick to a surface in little droplets (i.e. like water when it touches most surfaces because of intermolecular forces and surface tension). During the experiment I found that my fluid sim was just floating right the through the obstacle--not even a little interference with it. I don't use fluid sims much, so I'm probably making a rookie mistake, but regardless, I would like to know what's going on and how I can remedy this problem.

[image]

Also, heads up, I store my cache on a thumbdrive for various reasons, so you'll probably have to change the location to your computer's needs.